# override functions in swift

Tags: swift, overriding

Hello i'm trying to override like objective-c

```
class A {
class func myValue()->NSString? {

    return nil
}
}
```

and then

```
class B: A {
override class func myValue()->NSString? {
    return "username"
}
}
```

but still can't get the value returns nil

any ideas how to use?

Thanks

Comment: Is this in a subclass?

Comment: yes see above implementation

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling `A.myValue()`, the return value will be nil.

If you are calling `B.myValue()`, the return value will be "username".

The overridden method only applies to the class that overrides it. It does not affect the superclass. If you were to create a subclass of B called C, with a different implementation, then the return types for the superclasses remain unchanged.